# Reverse date order in script

Tags: php

I have a recruitment script written in PHP that I am working with at present. On our registrations page there is a drop down for date of birth which you can see in action here:
http://www.v3recruitment.com/users/register.php

As you can see, the date starts at 1900, what I would like to do is reverse the date order. I think I have found the code thats generating the dates, but my PHP is not good enough to work out how to get it to show dates in a reverse order, here is that code:

```
function FetchYears($type){
    $start = 1901;
    $end = date("Y");
    for($i=$start;$i<=$end;$i++){
        $array[]['year'] = $i;
    }
    return $array;
}
```

The front end is using Smarty Templates and here is that code:

```
      {section name="c" loop=$dob_years}
      <option value="{$dob_years[c].year}" {get_value field=select selectvalue=$dob_years[c].year fieldname="dob_year"}>{$dob_years[c].year}</option>
      {/section}
```

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: see [`array_reverse()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either reverse loop or use [array_reverse()](https://www.php.net/array_reverse)

change return `$array;` to `return array_reverse($array);`

For smarty it's very simple you don't have to even create this function in PHP it can be done in smarty as well.

```
{foreach $dob_years as $entry)
    <option value="{$entry.year}">{$entry.year}</option>
{/foreach}
```

**Check [HTML_SELECT_DATE](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.html.select.date) in smarty** or simply use just the code below doesn't require any additional php code.

```
 {assign var=currentYear value=$smarty.now|date_format:"%Y"}
 {assign var=fromYear value="2003"}
 {section name=years start=$currentYear step=-1 loop=$fromYear}
    {$smarty.section.years.index}
 {/section
```

Comment: You're welcome :) if this answer satisfy you, you can mark it as answer.

Answer (score 2):

[`array_reverse`](http://php.net/array_reverse) does what it says on the tin.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
function FetchYears($type){
    $start = date("Y");
    $end = 1901;
    for($i=$start;$i>=$end;$i--){
        $array[]['year'] = $i;
    }
    return $array;
}
```

or simply use `array_reverse` while returning your array like

```
function FetchYears($type){
    $start = 1901;
    $end = date("Y");
    for($i=$start;$i<=$end;$i++){
        $array[]['year'] = $i;
    }
    return array_reverse($array);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function FetchYears($type){
    $start = date("Y");
    $end = 1901;
    for($i=$start;$i>=$end;$i--){
        $array[]['year'] = $i;
    }
    return $array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i = $end; $i >= $start; $i--) {
        $array[]['year'] = $i;
}
```

Haven't tested it yet, should work :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to do this would be to put the dates in UTC (integer) format.

```
$dates[$i] = $timestamp;
```

Then use the PHP sort function to sort the dates.

```
sort($dates,SORT_NUMERIC);
```

You can use rsort for the opposite.

```
rsort($dates,SORT_NUMERIC);
```

When you are finished, iterate through your array and covert back using the date() function.

```
echo (date('m-d-Y', $dates[$i]));
```